# Is "For stars, engaging in conflicts likely harms their reputation" correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

Is this sentence correct?

> For stars, engaging in conflicts likely harms their reputation

I mean, using the sentence pattern like: for (somebody), doing something (+verb) + noun

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. As a reminder, this is not a proofreading service. If you can explain why you think the sentence is or is not correct in your own words, however, we can help you work through the applicable grammar,  I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: For stars, engaging in conflicts IS likely TO harm their reputation. (the idiomatic expression is "to be likely to do something").

Comment: See [this article](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2015/03/likely.html) talking about why at least some people (mainly Brits, and certainly including ***me***) don't like the cited usage of ***likely*** (with no preceding copula TO BE, and followed by the "tensed" verb form ***harms***). For me, that usage is ***very*** "colloquial, slangy", compared to *...engaging in conflicts **is** likely **to harm** their reputation* - especially given that ***engaging in conflicts*** is a relatively "elevated" register (effectively, a posh way of saying ***fighting*** here).

Answer (score 1):

In US usage at least  the form

> For stars, engaging in conflicts likely harms their reputation

is perfectly acceptable and not uncommon. It may be considered a reduced form of

> For stars, engaging in conflicts IS likely TO harm their reputation.

But I don't actually think so. The word "likely " here functions as an adverb, modifying "harms". The comment by @FumbleFingers  suggests that such a use of "likely" is "colloquial". But I don't see it that way at all, if anything I see it more in semi-formal registers, including some academic writing of a recent vintage.

Whether the more general form given in the question as "for (somebody), doing something (+verb) + noun" works well will depend very much on the verb in question, and exactly how "doing something" is expressed.